# How to change input type=“month” format?

Tags: html

Is there a way to show the month in numbers instead of names?

```
   <input type="month" />
```

Or there is a way to disable only days?

Comment: If support is of concern to you, you may want to use `date` instead (Firefox support). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: Why don't you use a `<select>` [combobox](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) instead of `<input>`?

Comment: Cristian - i need the years also.

Comment: Bram Vanroy - but how can i disable the days  in type date?